# What words are aquer?

Tags: lateral-thinking, word-property

Art, the arbiter, poses this riddle to George, the guesser:

> Some words are "aquer", some are not;
>
> The difference is simple yet profound.
>
> If you want to find an aquer word, you had better be certain,
>
> And not beat around the bush.
>
> Politicians will be good at this;
>
> Scientists, not so much.

After this, Harry the hint-giver, who knows the secret, enters into a conversation to try to help George figure out the riddle.

> Harry: For example, *abacus* is aquer.
>
> Art: Correct.
>
> Harry: And so is *beatific*.
>
> Art: Correct.
>
> George: OK, let me guess one: Is *werewolf* aquer?
>
> Art: No.
>
> George: How about *apple*?
>
> Art: No.
>
> Harry: But *banana* is.
>
> Art: Correct.
>
> George: OK, I think I might see the pattern.  So, *horticulture* would be aquer.
>
> Art: Correct.
>
> George: But *agriculture* would not be.
>
> Art: Actually, no, *agriculture* is also aquer.
>
> George: Hmm, that destroys my idea...  (Thinks for a bit.)
>
> George: Is *aquer* itself an aquer word?
>
> Art: No.
>
> Harry: For another example, *olfactory* isn't aquer, is it, Art?
>
> Art: No, it's not.
>
> Harry: But *nasal* is.
>
> Art: Correct.

At the end of this conversation, George is left utterly perplexed as to what the criterion might be.  Can you spot it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick to this is that

> the words themselves don't actually matter: the "aquer" words are those that are in *declarations*. If you ask, they are not aquer; if you make a statement, they are.

The opening riddle gives hints to this:

> "You had better be certain" hints that making statements is necessary. "Politicians will be good at this; Scientists, not so much" plays with the stereotype that politicians make statements that they aren't sure to be true, and references the fact that science is all about inquiry.

Comment: www.rot13.com: Vapvqragnyyl, V pbvarq "ndhre" hfvat gur cersvk *n-* naq "dhre" nf na nooerivngvba bs "dhrel".

Comment: @DanielSchepler - ah, nice! I suspected that, but wasn't sure